# Nginx: Cache only home page

Tags: nginx, cache

How do I specify the location directive to cache my homepage without any filename or extension suffix.

I need to cache only my home page at site.com and not anything under it(i.e site.com/page.php).

Answer (score 4):

Declare location with strict match and caching within it:

```
location = / {
      proxy_pass ...;
      proxy_cache ...;
}
```